# Use multiple hibernate entities that are loaded from database

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is the scenario:

1. One object/entity gets loaded from the database using hibernate.
2. Some manipulation of that object is performed before saving it again to DB
3. I need the state of the object as it is in the DB, that is, before changing the original state of the object, so I load an object from the database again into the new object instance.
4. I use the secondly loaded object (that object doesn't have any further interactions with the DB)
5. Firstly loaded object (from step 1) is persisted to the database to update it's state and that this exception is thrown:
   `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:...`

I get that not more that one entity object cat be used in the same hibernate session. But I need object from step 3. only to retrieve it's current state from the database, so hibernate don't need to keep track of it in any way, I just need it as a POJO. Is there any way to remove it from the session / cache or wherever the hibernate stores that instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each EntityManager aka PersistenceContext aka HibernateSession has its own cache. Just create a second and load the entity again from the database without interfering with the first one. As long as the first one hasn't synchronized the changes to the database, you will get the original values. Just make sure you know when synchronization (aka merge) is happening exactly in your application.

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you very much.